# Loopback - querying related models from MongoDB performance

Tags: mysql, mongodb, loopback

In MySQL, there exists Join query which optimizes the query two related tables. However, in MongoDB there is non due to its no-relational nature.

Loopback does support Query related model [Here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-related-models.html)

I wonder of the underlying mechanism and the performance too. What does Loopback actually does in case of MongoDB? Should I execute the query by sending two separate requests, or should I use Loopback's API? Thanks.

p/s: When I write this question, I am thinking of experimenting to see the result myself. But I would love to hear opinion from experts also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but for me, both have the same performance. In my project, I use `mongodb` and `postgressql`. Not only there is relation between tables, but I also implemented inter relation ie. from `mongo` to `postgres` and everything works fine.

I prefer `mongodb` when using loopback framework, as everything is javascript.

Here is the link for [data-model-relation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer containing the inner mechanism of Loopback's join query. 
[Answer on Official Loopback's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/loopbackjs/g_rTbC0zj3E/3VeOjmgPCwAJ)